# How do you call an instance method from Class "B" from within Class "A"?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I'm not sure if I'm using classes correctly. I'm attempting to build a simple menu using pygame. This is my first foray into gui stuff. I have no idea how to structure my code.

I found that I could make a general Button class to handle all of the mouse over/mouse click stuff, and then I can subclass that for each button, and override the `do_action` method to give each button a specific action.

```
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global screen_flags
    def __init__(self, images, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = images
        self.image = images[0]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(pos)


    def update(self, events, surface):
        # if not screen_flags['config']:
        for event in events:
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    self.image = self.images[1]
                else:
                    self.image = self.images[0]
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1 and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    self.image = self.images[-1]
                    screen_flags['config'] = 1
                    self.do_action()
                    self.set_flag()

            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.image = self.images[0]


        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def do_action(self):
        pass
    def set_flag(self):
        pass


class CheckBox(Button):
    def __init__(self, images, pos):
        Button.__init__(self, images, pos)
        self.is_clicked = False

    def update(self, events, surface):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if not self.is_clicked:
                    if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        self.image = self.images[1]
                    else:
                        self.image = self.images[0]
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1 and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if not self.is_clicked:
                        self.image = self.images[-1]
                        self.is_clicked = True
                    else:
                        self.image = self.images[0]
                        self.is_clicked = False
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Cancel(Button):
    def do_action(self):
        screen_flags['config'] = 0
```

So, as you can see,they don't really *do* anything yet. I can toggle the check box on and off, and open and close one 'config' window, but that's as far as I've gotten. The rest of the code:

```
global count
global sTime



config_button_img = load_sliced_images(25, 25, c_buttons)
config_button = Button(config_button_img, (608,4))

input_bar = load_sliced_images(351,33, inpt_bar)
text_box = Textbox(input_bar, (144,155))

s_button = load_sliced_images(110,32, sbmt_bttn)
submit = Button(s_button, (241,301))

c_button = load_sliced_images(110,32, cncl_bttn)
cancel = Cancel(c_button, (385, 301))

c_boxes = load_sliced_images(20,19, chk_box)
check_box = CheckBox(c_boxes, (200,200))    

try:
    while True:
        # ****************************
        # Pygame section
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                screen_flags['alert'] = 1
                ding.play(0,1000)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                text_box.set_focus(event.button, event.pos)





        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(client_logo, (0,30))
        screen.blit(tag, (174,462))

        if screen_flags['config']:
            screen.blit(config_window_img, (0,0))

            submit.update(events, screen)
            cancel.update(events, screen)
            check_box.update(events, screen)
        if screen_flags['alert']:
            screen.blit(alert_dialog, (0,0))

        config_button.update(events, screen)
        pygame.display.update()   








except KeyboardInterrupt:
    try: 
        pygame.quit()
    except:
        pass
```

So this works kind of as expected. I'm unsure where to go from here. Do I continue to wrap up logic inside of the classes? For instance, the next thing I'm attempting to do is make it so that when the "cancel" button is clicked it unchecks the check box.

I tried changing the `Cancel` class to do just that.

```
class Cancel(Button):
    def do_action(self):
        screen_flags['config'] = 0
        check_box.is_clicked=False
```

However, this is giving me a GlobalName Error. How do I target an instance method from within a different class? Is this even the correct way to go about it? Or have only some logic, like the `update()` stuff to take care of the mouse, in then handle what the classes *do* by passing variables to and from the different classes fro `main()`? Should I have all of the classes use global variables?

Is there any good articles on gui practices. Things like how to structure code etc..?

Hopefully the above makes sense.

Comment: Just get a reference to the class `A` object and call the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would make it so that each of my classes accepted `screen_flags` as an argument to the constructor (`__init__`).  Then each of your classes would have a handle on the "global" data that they need.  A real easy way to do this is...

```
class Cancel(Button):
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
          self.screen_flags=kwargs.pop('screen_flags')
          Button.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)  #Some might advise you to use super here...

      def do_action(self):
          self.screen_flags['config'] = 0

#now use the cancel class
cancel=Cancel(c_button, (385, 301),screen_flags=screen_flags)
```

Of course, depending on what the shared data looks like (how many different variables you have, etc), you might want to pass a dictionary, or other object to make it so you don't need to pass 5000 different pieces of shared data around.

Another way of dealing with this is to define your "global" data in a class as "class variables" and then inherit from that class.

```
class GlobalData(object):
   stuff=None

class FooButton(Button,GlobalData):
   def do_action(self):
       print self.stuff
       #If you do something in here, don't do:  self.stuff = blah
       #instead, you *should* do: GlobalData.stuff = blah
       #However, it is fine to change mutable objects in place.
       #         e.g. self.stuff["dict_key"]=blah

#Now we can assign to GlobalData and instances of 
#FooButton will see the differences immediately.
cancel=FooButton(c_button, (385, 301))
cancel.do_action()
GlobalData.stuff="Cows say Moo"
cancel.do_action()
```

I hope this helps.  There was a lot in you post, so sorting through it all was a little difficult.

**EDIT**

In case you don't understand how class variables are handled, see the comments in `do_action`.  Basically, you need to be careful that you don't lose a handle on your data...

Comment: This is cool. Thanks! I really like the GlobalData Class idea. Seems like it'll be easy to keep track of everything. Thanks!!

Comment: @Zack -- No problem.  Glad to help.  I've never used pygame, I'm a Tkinter guy myself.  It's interesting to see some of the different ways of doing things.  There is one downfall of the GlobalData class that i just thought of...I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

GUI stuff can be done nicer.

Yes, do wrap your control in classes.

I'd recommend to try this.

First, **define logical interface for your controls**. Forget about implementation details for a minute. Any control can be clicked; define method `onClick(pos)`. Check boxes can be checked or unchecked; define `setChecked(bool)`. Windows can be shown or hidden, define `setVisible(bool)`, etc.

Create a **common ancestor for clickable controls**. Within its event handler, call `onClick(event.pos)`. The default implementation would do nothing. Now you can call `onClick()` of a control when you want to imitate a click. You will want `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` to do things like click animation, `onMouseIn` and `onMouseOut` for hover events, etc. The only place where you'll care about the gory details of event dispatch will be your common ancestor.

**Don't refer directly to global state**; it leads to all sorts of unpleasant things. Instead, let every control know its state and how to change it (we're doing OOP anyway). So, the check box gets a `isChecked()` method, etc.

Now Cancel button would only have to override its `onClick` method and constructor. In constructor, pass the `CheckBox` instance; in `cancel_button.onClick` just call `Button.onClick` and then `self.check_box.setChecked(False)`.